# WPF Combobox, Binding Display a Tooltip in the drop-down list, but also on the Text

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding

I am trying to display the list of my COM ports in a Combobox,
I recovered all the data I need, namely the COM Ports, (COM1 / COM6 / COMetc..), but also their designation (Communication Port / USB Device / etc..)

At the ComboBox level I display the list COM1, COM6 etc. but I would like to display there also in a ToolTip on mouseover for the designation.

I manage to display the Tootip on the ComboBox, but in the list it is displayed but empty, I cannot find the data binding that I must use.

For the source of the combobox I use an ObservableColection which contains my "ComboList" class

ComboList =

```
public class ComboList
{
    private int _Id;
    [XmlAttribute("Id")]
    public int Id
    {
        get { return _Id; }
        set { _Id = value; }
    }
    private string _name;
    [XmlAttribute("Name")]
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set { _name = value; }
    }
    private string _tooltip;
    [XmlAttribute("Tooltip")]
    public string Tooltip
    {
        get { return _tooltip; }
        set { _tooltip = value; }
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
 <ComboBox Name="CMB_PortCOM"
     Width="90"
     Style="{StaticResource MyCombo}"
     Margin="5,10,5,10"
     DisplayMemberPath="Name"
     SelectedValuePath="Id"
     ItemsSource="{Binding CMB_PortCOM_Source}"
     SelectedValue="{Binding CMB_PortCOM_SelectedValue}"
     SelectedItem="{Binding CMB_PortCOM_SelectedItem}"
     ToolTip="{Binding CMB_PortCOM_TooTip}">
     <ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="ToolTip">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ToolTip}" />
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
     </ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
 </ComboBox>
```

I use a rather substantial "Style" to have something prettier, I hope it won't give me trouble.

[ToolTip OK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DnbmQ.png)

It's OK for this

But not OK for the list:

[ToolTip not OK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jK5TW.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use an ItemTemplate:

```
 <ComboBox Name="CMB_PortCOM"
     Width="90"
     Style="{StaticResource MyCombo}"
     Margin="5,10,5,10"
     DisplayMemberPath="Name"
     SelectedValuePath="Id"
     ItemsSource="{Binding CMB_PortCOM_Source}"
     SelectedValue="{Binding CMB_PortCOM_SelectedValue}"
     SelectedItem="{Binding CMB_PortCOM_SelectedItem}"
     ToolTip="{Binding CMB_PortCOM_TooTip}">
     <ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="ToolTip">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ToolTip}" />
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
     </ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>

     <!-- Here you can specify the Items including the Tooltip for each Item-->
     <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
           <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" 
                      ToolTip="{Binding Path=ToolTip}"  /> 
        </DataTemplate>
     </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
 </ComboBox>
```